# Can a fragment host navigation graph?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am using navigation architecture component. i have a requirement where i need to host navigation graph in one of the fragments of ViewPager.
can we host navigation graph in a fragment? any example is welcome.

Comment: yes, it can i will attach a github link soon